# Get attribute value by passing node name dynamically in Xpath

Tags: xpath, dynamic, attributes

One of the job pulled the files and wrote the data as shown below.

```
    <Data>
      <rootDirectory>home</rootDirectory>
      <time>20160330124434437</time>
      <STE_Document1 filename="REPORT_20160328.csv"/>
      <STE_Document2 filename="REPORT_20160328_2.csv"/>
      <STE_Document3 filename="REPORT_20160328_3.csv"/>
      <STE_DocumentCount>3</STE_DocumentCount>
      <DcNbr>1</DcNbr>
    </Data>
```

I have used the xpath statement to retrieve the attribute value `filename` from First node.

```
string(/Data/STE_Document1/@filename)
```

Instead of hardcoding the node name `STE_Document1` in xpath , is there a way to provide the trailing number for the node dynamically?

I have loop counter `/DcNbr` within the job I can use for the trailing number.

I tried

```
string(/Data/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'STE')][position=1]/@filename)
```

but it is returning blank.

Comment: string(/Data/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'STE')][1]/@filename)

Comment: or string(/Data/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'STE')][position()=1]/@filename)

Comment: position is a function

Comment: Thanks @splash58.. that worked.
I modified the xpath to pull dynamically
//*[starts-with(name(),'STE')][position()=//DocNbr/text()]/@filename